# Changing local scope in a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I need a directive with a local scope, that local scope would be updated in the following way:

```
var update;
angular.module('docsTransclusionExample', [])
   .directive('myDialog', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {},
      templateUrl: 'my-dialog.html',
      link: function (scope, element) {
        scope.name = 'Jeff';

          update = function(name){
              scope.name = name;
          };
      }
    };
  });
```

Now something from the outside would call update and pass in a name.
As it is now ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U53xT/1/)) , however, the name won't get updated on the screen. What am I missing? Can anyone help? Thanks.

--EDIT--
Forgot to add - this is a simplification, but at some point instead of calling a function on button-click, the directive will subscribe to a service, that will be pushing the data to it in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your update function is not a part of angular's scope, you will need to trigger a scope.$apply manually to have angular update the value everywhere else.  Add this to your update function:

```
scope.$apply();
```

Comment: ah great, missed that little thing even tho I saw it in other places. thanks :)